# Paypal and holding payments

Tags: paypal, payments

We are looking to update the way we deal with subscriptions on our news site. We offer the chance to allow people to subscribe. We also want to have management services to allow people to add their own events and job ads to the site. This would carry a charge and we want to have payments through this.

The idea is we have the following process:

- User puts their ad online
- User inserts payment details (we don't really want these on our
  server)
- Editorial get a message regarding
- the upload Editorial checks and edits the article and approves it
- Client is informed and asked to check they are happy.
- We make the item live and remove a hold on the payment
- Payment goes from clients account

So we want to know if there is a way of incoming payments being held in paypal by default and us having to approve them (alongside any hold paypal make for themselves). If not with Paypal, is there another system that would allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like this is what you need:

https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_admin_authcapture

enjoy!